# Multiple threads in application - design convention?

Tags: java, multithreading, design-patterns

Assume that in java we have some object/ group of them (service object, controllers, etc.) which we are using in our single thread application. Let's call this object by "A".

After some time we are extending our thread model and want to use these objects also in other threads (for example listener thread, etc.).

Of course in such a case we have to be aware of synchronization issues and so on. But a developer who was till now using object "A" can not be aware our architecture change and if he will add something to class/ (object) "A" he possibly may not properly handle synchronization.
Of course this developer should check all occurrences of class "A" in the code, but if he is not accustomed that this class is used in multi-thread environment he may not do it.

My question is... Is there any good pattern for that situation, which marks that class/ (object) "A" as "multi-thread usable". For example implementation of some interface only for 'information' purposes, etc.

Comment: You can check [the javadoc of the java.util.concurrent package](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html) or one of the many contained classes. Javadoc is a good place to indicate that a class is thread safe and what guarantees are provided if any.

Comment: I'm afraid that the best you can do is to add some highly visible comments and future developers will need to take care of the synchronization...

Comment: Good javadoc is for sure great idea, but maybe I could provide some observer pattern behaviour to make class A more 'threads aware' for example make 'class A observer' for some 'observable threads' which seems to be similar to create some specific interface for 'class A' which marks that this class is used by many threads, and which expose explicitly only some method to use in other threads. It doesn't protect against not thread safe implementation totally but at least shows sensitive points. But it's just an idea I am not sure I like.

Comment: @assylias I of course agree with javadoc. java.util.concurrent package is not a good examples because here the package name indicates that it has something to do with threads. but of course I agree with javadoc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually put a comment in the JavaDoc at the top of the code, indicating that something is intended for multi-threaded use.

I often add unit tests too, so that the use is clear.

It is then up to other developers to read the documentation and unit tests, so that they are aware of the intended usage.

Answer (score 1):

It should be possible to create a thread-safe version of "A", if this object is [loosely coupled](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loose_coupling) with all its clients.

An example directly from the JDK:

```
java.lang.Appendable - the interface
java.lang.StringBuilder - regular implementation
java.lang.StringBuffer - thread-safe implementation
```

The client doesn't have to know, if it's a thread-safe version, since it's using the object indirectly, through an interface:

```
void doSomething(Appendable a) {
   a.append(...);
}
```

From a practical standpoint, using [inversion of control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control) can significantly help. Use interfaces for business contract declaration and Spring (or any other dependency injection framework) for component injection (whether it's thread-safe or not depends on the configuration only).

**Bottom line:** you can prevent such problems with **loose coupling** and smart architecture design (separation of concerns etc.).

Comment: To be honest I am not sure which of these two answers yours or Chris to accept. Because I know we could create some interface which marks that class's object is accessed from many threads,etc., but this is a bit redundant. Appendable interface has nothing to do with threads. And how do you know that StringBuffer is thread safe? Because you can read it in javadoc. But in a project it can be a bit tricky. I am not sure if all developers read all javadoc updates. But I think javadoc seems to be really good place to describe behaviour and it doesn't complicate implementation. hmmm... :)

Comment: My point is: you shouldn't expose concurrency outside the component.  Appendable doesn't "mark" your class as thread-safe. It is a business contract, that states: you can append a CharSequence to this "thing". Nothing more. If you need, a thread-safe implementation, then you will instantiate a StringBuffer. Otherwise, it would be more efficient to use a StringBuilder. The client doesn't have to know about the synchronization mechanisms, that are used internally to protect the state. Same thing applies to the service "world" (take EJBs for an example).

Comment: On another note: "updating javadocs" on an existing component doesn't really affect any real life situations. It's just like saying "it's not my business, the client should adapt and I don't really care - read the CHANGELOG, if you get into any problems". Also, unit tests won't help you much in this case, since reliable testing of concurrency can be really tricky (detecting deadlocks and process starvation for example).

Comment: ... but how do you know that that StringBuilder doesn't care about threads, and StringBuffer does? Because you see in documentation. 'A mutable sequence of characters. This class provides an API compatible with StringBuffer, but with no guarantee of synchronization. This class is designed for use as a drop-in replacement for StringBuffer in places where the string buffer was being used by a single thread (as is generally the case). Where possible, it is recommended that this class be used in preference to StringBuffer as it will be faster under most implementations. '.

Comment: ... but I agree that we would have to have a concrete problem, and it's hard to give here one opinion. Thanks for your input.

Comment: Of course! That's what javadoc is supposed to do :) The class or - more likely - the container, needs to know what it's using. However, that doesn't change the fact, that you were asking about a "design pattern". Informing someone about the contract is hardly a design pattern, more a necessity :) Good luck on your project!